# Keeping zero value in reverse string javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to reverse a string in javascript and keep zero value.

```
function reverseNumb(a) {
  let reverse = Array.from(String(a),Number).reverse();
    return Number(reverse.join(''));
}

reverseNumb(01234567);
```

It keeps on removing the 0 and if you add 0 it gives a totally different number

Would like it to keep the number zero and not change the value to something different wen adding the number 0

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what does not work? please add the wanted result.

Comment: Added the unwanted result

Comment: `01234567` is not a string.  You're seeing Octal notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are looking at a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number) data type, if it has a leading zero that zero is disregarded as being meaningless. If you are talking about a base 10 number system, and not binary or octal or hex or whatever else, `0100`, or even `000000100` are both just equal to `100`. So the number, `01234567` is rightly read and stored as a Number as `1234567`.

---

**EDIT:** *Just to be clear here, in the actual code if you are not explicit that you are in base 10, a leading* `0` *will cause the number to be read and stored as an octal value (or a hex value if the leading* `0` *is followed by an* `x`*) in some operations. So the statement,* `let num = 0100` *results in* `num` *being saved with the value of* `64` *in loose mode and a SyntaxError being thrown in Strict Mode. However,* `parseInt("0100", 10)`, `Number("0100")`, `"0100"|0`, *and* `+"0100"` *are all equal to* `100`.

---

If you want to keep a leading zero, you would be better served representing the data as a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/String), which you can do simply by wrapping it in quotation marks: `reverseNums("01234567")`. If you need to have the function return numbers that also contain leading zeros you will need to return a string, which you can do by simply not casting it to a number in your return statement: `return rev.join('')`

However, since you are now using a string as input, you can write a more simple string reversal function by using the [split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) from the String object to first convert your input into an Array, and then chaining the rest of your methods after that, like this:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

You could also write a string reversal function using the modern, less verbose, ES6+ syntax by using an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like this:

```js
const reverseString = str => str.split('').reverse().join('');
```

Comment: this is your answer, it is a leading 0 problem

Comment: Yes, this is my answer, and this is a leading zero problem. Well spotted.

Comment: *"So the number, 01234567 is rightly read and stored as a Number as 1234567."* Well, no, not in JavaScript. :-) It's either a legacy octal literal (loose mode) or a syntax error (strict mode). But your main points are of course spot on.

Comment: Go back and read the sentence directly before that where I say, "If you are talking about a base 10 numbering system and not binary or octal..." You are technically correct though that if you write `let num = 0100` it will be saved as `64`.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed already in other answers by with number we can't but string you can like as follows

```js
var reverse=num=>num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')

console.log(reverse("012345"))

console.log(reverse("543210"))
```